# Run a multi line script from a variable

Tags: autoit

My AutoIt script:

```
$command = InputBox("Enter your command", "Enter your command")
Execute($command)
```

This works for single line commands like `MsgBox(0, "Test", "Test")`. But multi line code (such as `If` -statements) produce an error.

Is there a way to run AutoIt source code from a variable if it is a multi line script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, write it to a temporary script file and then execute that script. Since InputBox() doesn't accept multiline input, I'm using clipget() to grab the commands from the clipboard instead.

```
$command=clipget()
$tempfilename="tempscript.au3"
$tempscript=FileOpen($tempfilename,2)
FileWrite($tempscript,$command)
FileFlush($tempscript)
FileClose($tempscript)
RunWait(@AutoItExe & ' /AutoIt3ExecuteScript ' & $tempfilename)
FileDelete($tempfilename)
```